# Is there any situation where an article could be used in front of a pronoun?

Tags: articles, pronouns, early-modern-english

I was reading an online copy of the King James Bible and (in John 18:1) found this:

> When Jesus had spoken these words, he went forth with his disciples over the brook Cedron, where was a garden, into the which he entered, and his disciples.

The whole thing is fantastically archaic, but the notable part is `into the which he entered`.  Obviously he entered into 'the garden' (the thing just mentioned), but surely `into the which` should just be `into which`, or possibly `whereinto`, `whither`, or really any of the dozens of archaicisms to choose from.  I think I'm going mad thinking about this.  Is is, in any way (even archaically), correct?

Comment: A more recent example: “*From thence to the third chamber , which was hanged with very rich arras , in the which there was a cloth of estate and as rich a bed as I have ever seen*”; https://books.google.it/books?id=zXvYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22the+which%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP_r3QxZzvAhWSKewKHbVRBSo4ChDoATAGegQIAxAD#v=onepage&q=%22the%20which%22&f=false

Comment: Of course it was correct in 1611, otherwise it would not have been written that way!

Comment: @user66974 - Not actually more recent, as it seems to be a quotation from Henry VIII's time - but confirms that it was an established usage.

Comment: You need to be more careful in your questions: "any circumstances" includes the trivial "If "it" is the first word of a sentence, the it need to be capitalised." / "The he I am referring to is John." However, the commonest example must be **the one** I am writing now."

Answer (score 1):

Is appears to be a Middle English usage as suggested by [A Grammar of the English Language, Volume 2 by George Oliver Curme](https://books.google.it/books?id=P7RZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22in%20the%20which%22&dq=%22in%20the%20which%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAy87Vx5zvAhWL6qQKHf5FAi4Q6AEwAXoECAQQAw):

> Instead of the determinatives so — so we often find others in older English , especially the and that , as *in the which , which that , the which that* , the usual forms in Middle English, referring to either persons or things. *The which* began to appear in Old English.